# regular expression for occurrences of a string

Tags: regex, grep

I have a simple problem I can't seem to find an answer to.  I need a regular expression that searches for all occurrences of a particular string.  for example, if I were searching for any number pf occurrences of the string "hi", then I would get matches on strings like:

```
hihi
12hi11h
hi34hi
```

but not on:

```
hh1ii
iiihh1h
```

Comment: in this case, for use with `fgrep` in linux

Comment: i might.  im searching text files for a regex.  is that not what `fgrep` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex to match a string is the string itself.

Remember to escape any special characters, though.

For an example, the string that matches any number of occurrences of "hi" is: `hi`

NOTE: in `egrep`, you need to put your regex in single quotes: `egrep '(hi){2,}' file.txt`

Comment: is there a way to match a given number, such as 2 or more occurrences of "hi"?

Comment: @ewok You can create a bash script that only executes `fgrep` a specified number of times.

Comment: @ewok: You could do something like `(hi.*){2}`, which means: The text `hi` followed by anything, repeated two times.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm that doesnt seem to work.  is tells me `(` is an illegal character

Comment: @ewok: What exactly are you typing?

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm `fgrep (hi.*){2} file.txt`  i also tried `fgrep "(hi.*){2}" file.txt`

Comment: @ewok: fgrep doesn't use regular expressions. Also, you need to quote your regex.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm as Alex pointed out above, i think i need to be using `egrep`.  however, the regex you gave me doesnt work there either

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15068/discussion-between-sebastian-paaske-torholm-and-ewok)